# fontComboBox QSettings application unexpectedly quits

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qsettings

I am trying to implement QSettings in an editor of mine. I am trying to implement it for font changes. However, whenever I start up my program it exits immediately.

Here's my code:

When I change the font in my font box.

```
    void SquareIDE::on_fontBox_currentFontChanged(const QFont &f)
    {
        ui->fontBox->setFont(f);
        ui->textEdit->setMarginsFont(f);
        lexer1->setFont(f);
        settings.setValue("font", f);
    }
```

On start up when it loads the settings.

```
    void SquareIDE::loadSettings()
    {
        dee = settings.value("dee", true).toBool();
        autosave = settings.value("autosave", true).toBool();
        font = settings.value("font", f).toString();
        QFont font1 = font;
        if (dee == true) {
            ui->dee->setChecked(true);
        }
        if (autosave == true) {
            ui->autosave->setChecked(true);
        }
        ui->fontBox->setCurrentFont(font1);
    }
```

Debugger Output:

```
    Function: _ZN9SquareIDE29on_fontBox_currentFontChangedERK5QFont
0x4099ce  <+0x004e>         add    %al,(%rax)
0x4099d0  <+0x0050>         mov    0x90(%rbx),%rdi
0x4099d7  <+0x0057>         mov    $0xffffffff,%edx
0x4099dc  <+0x005c>         mov    %rbp,%rsi
0x4099df  <+0x005f>         mov    (%rdi),%rax
0x4099e2  <+0x0062>         callq  *0x150(%rax)
0x4099e8  <+0x0068>         mov    %rbp,%rsi
0x4099eb  <+0x006b>         mov    %r12,%rdi
0x4099ee  <+0x006e>         callq  0x406020 <_ZNK5QFontcv8QVariantEv@plt>
0x4099f3  <+0x0073>         lea    0x8a7b(%rip),%rdi        # 0x412475
0x4099fa  <+0x007a>         mov    $0x4,%esi
0x4099ff  <+0x007f>         callq  0x405c70 <_ZN7QString16fromAscii_helperEPKci@plt>
0x409a04  <+0x0084>         lea    0x98(%rbx),%rdi
0x409a0b  <+0x008b>         mov    %r12,%rdx
0x409a0e  <+0x008e>         mov    %rsp,%rsi
0x409a11  <+0x0091>         mov    %rax,(%rsp)
0x409a15  <+0x0095>         mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x409a18  <+0x0098>         callq  0x406430 <_ZN9QSettings8setValueERK7QStringRK8QVariant@plt>
0x409a1d  <+0x009d>         mov    (%rsp),%rdi
0x409a21  <+0x00a1>         mov    (%rdi),%eax
0x409a23  <+0x00a3>         test   %eax,%eax
0x409a25  <+0x00a5>         jne    0x409a60 <_ZN9SquareIDE29on_fontBox_currentFontChangedERK5QFont+224>
0x409a27  <+0x00a7>         mov    $0x8,%edx
0x409a2c  <+0x00ac>         mov    $0x2,%esi
0x409a31  <+0x00b1>         callq  0x406250        <_ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_mm@plt>
0x409a36  <+0x00b6>         mov    %r12,%rdi
0x409a39  <+0x00b9>         callq  0x405cd0 <_ZN8QVariantD1Ev@plt>
0x409a3e  <+0x00be>         mov    0x28(%rsp),%rax
0x409a43  <+0x00c3>         xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
```

See when I comment out the new QSettings code:

```
    void SquareIDE::loadSettings()
    {
        dee = settings.value("dee", true).toBool();
        autosave = settings.value("autosave", true).toBool();
        //font = settings.value("font", f).toString();
        //QFont font1 = font;
        if (dee == true) {
            ui->dee->setChecked(true);
        }
        if (autosave == true) {
            ui->autosave->setChecked(true);
        }
        //ui->fontBox->setCurrentFont(font1);
    }
```

I compiles and runs fine.

QFont f can be used outside the function because it was also defined in squareide.h

```
    private:
    ...
    QFont f;
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger and post the stack trace

Comment: The stack trace in assembler is almost totally useless.

Comment: Will anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program seemed to have a problem with this one line:

```
    lexer1->setFont(f);
```

So, I figured I would make it so that way every time the lexer was changed I would make it so the lexer automatically sets its font to the font set in the font combo box like so:

```
    void SquareIDE::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(QString i)
    {
        if (i=="JavaScript") {
            QsciLexer *lexer1(new QsciLexerJavaScript);
            lexer1->setFont(ui->fontBox->currentFont());
        }
        if (i=="HTML") {
            QsciLexer *lexer1(new QsciLexerHTML);
            lexer1->setFont(ui->fontBox->currentFont());
        }
        if (i=="SquareScript") {
            QsciLexer *lexer1(new QsciLexerJavaScript);
            lexer1->setFont(ui->fontBox->currentFont());
            QsciAPIs *api = new QsciAPIs(lexer1);
            api->add("clear");
            api->add("canvas");
            api->add("stroke");
            api->add("fill");
            api->add("noStroke");
            api->add("noFill");
            api->add("rect");
            api->add("triangle");
            api->add("circle");
            api->add("arc");
            api->add("font");
            api->add("text");
            api->add("h1");
            api->add("h2");
            api->add("h3");
            api->add("h4");
            api->add("h5");
            api->add("h6");
            api->add("p");
            api->add("title");
            api->add("video");
            api->add("mute");
            api->add("controls");
            api->add("preload");
            api->add("autoplay");
            api->add("audio");
            api->add("loop");
            api->prepare();
            ui->textEdit->setLexer(lexer1);
        }
    }
```

Then I was able to call this function on the font change:

```
    void SquareIDE::on_fontBox_currentFontChanged(const QFont &f)
    {
        this->setFont(f);
        ui->fontBox->setFont(f);
        ui->textEdit->setMarginsFont(f);
        settings.setValue("font", f);
        on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(ui->comboBox->currentText());
    }
```

This completely solved my problem.

Comment: OK. I think I still have no idea what you were trying to do as you didn't specify the types of most of your variables. But at least it's working.

Comment: By the way, please don't write stuff like this->setFont(). It's just setFont().

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have infinite recursion - in your fontBox currentFontChanged slot, you change the font, which will cause the event to run again:

```
void SquareIDE::on_fontBox_currentFontChanged(const QFont &f)
{
    ui->fontBox->setFont(f);
```

You don't need that line.

And your stack trace, almost useless as it is, shows the crash is occurring inside the currentFontChanged slot on the line

```
    settings.setValue("font", a);
```

What is a? It is used in your code in several places but not declared in what you posted. Appears to be an invalid variant at the time of that setValue() call.

Comment: That is not the problem. I had that before I added the QSettings code. It doesn't change the current font it is on. So, it changes it so the font box prints the font that it is currently on in that font.

Comment: What is ui->fontBox anyway? What type of widget?

Comment: woops that's supposed to be f..sorry

Comment: ui->fontBox is a QFontComboBox